# jquery: Update variable number of values using $.post

Tags: php, jquery

i want to update variable number of items in ajax. What i have is

```
<input name="cart[qty][25]" id="25" value="10" size="4" title="Qty" class="input-text qty">
```

suppose there are 10 similar fields in my form and lots of other fields too which don't need to be updated.

i want to update the item quantity in cart whose id is equal to the id of the text field. I know it can easily be done in php using

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
  foreach($_POST['cart']['qty'] as $k=>$v)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

But i want this in $.post something like

```
jQuery(".update-cart").on('click',function(){
  jQuery(".cart-item").each(function(){
  var  id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
  var qty = jQuery(this).val();
    //What should i do here and on my php file ?
  });
});
```

Comment: you have same id's on same page....??

Comment: yes suppose there are 10 number of fields on the page

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jquery serialize method.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize

Update:

```
jQuery(".update-cart").on('click',function(){
jQuery(".cart-item").each(function(){
 if(jQuery(this).hasClass('qty'))
 {
   var  id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
   var qty = jQuery(this).val();
 }
 //What should i do here and on my php file ?
 });
});
```

OR

```
jQuery(".update-cart").on('click',function(){
   alert($('.qty').serialize());
});
```

Comment: Yes i know but that would send all the fields. I need the fields which has a class of qty.